# GAE creating and reversing a PropertyOrder

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to create a method that supports queries with pagination

```
def page(cls, query, order, prev_str, next_str, count):
```

to which I want to pass the ordering as a parameter

On some places I want to use the same ordering and on other places I want to use the reverse ordering.

My issue is that when I pass the ordering as reverse (`-Obj.value`), then I can't reverse it any more in the method. It would be `--Obj.value`, which gives

```
TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'PropertyOrder'
```

Is there another way to reverse order?

Perhaps from the `PropertyOrder`object?
In which case, is there a way to create `PropertyOrder`from `*Property`?

```
order = -Obj.value
```

has the type `PropertyOrder`

```
order = Obj.value
```

has the type `*Property`

Comment: Would parentheses help?

Comment: Parentheses don't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you do something like this?

```
query1 = Account.query()

if order == 'desc':
    query2 = query1.order(-Account.userid)
else:
    query2 = query1.order(Account.userid)
```

... etc.  Or even use the GQL syntax, where you can tell it the order directly:

```
...ORDER BY userid ASC
```

See: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/gqlreference#Syntax

**UPDATE**

If you are trying to reverse some page in the middle of a multi-page query (using a cursor), `.fetch` the cursored query as a list, then `list.reverse()` it before sending to the browser.  Or, do the magic in javascript in the browser.

Comment: As a hack I currently have order always as ascending and I have additional parameter to determine whether the order should be flipped or not. So similar to your first suggestion. I don't like this approach though, because it introduces additional parameter parameter and I can't operate on the order as nice as I would like.

As far as I understand GQL would need different model and wouldn't mix with query from NDB, right?

Comment: It doesn't introduce any other parameter.  If you want to change the ordering, you must have `order` as a parameter.

Comment: I want to have a order as a parameter. In the method that I created I need to use the ordering in the same way as it was given and also as reversed. As far as I know it's impossible to reverse descending order (and I do want to support descending orders). So the hack I mentioned before (which is similar to your first suggestion) is that I always give an ascending order as a parameter together with another parameter that is specifying whether the ordering should be ascending or descending (I consider this second parameter as introduced parameter and it's currently mandatory).

Comment: Are you talking about changing the order somewhere in the middle of a query?  IOW, on the 3rd page of 10 pages of results?  See update

Comment: Yes and no, my full query is a single page, I wanted to query for a specific cursor (which would correspond to a single page), a parameter would need to tell me whether to read it backwards or forwards (cursor can be either the end or the beginning of the page).

Comment: `.fetch()` the query, then do a `list.reverse()` if `order == "desc"` and send the reversed list to the browser.